# running some process on the file before serving

Tags: .net-core

I have upload attachment endpoint that do the following:

- convert the file to bytes
- convert the  bytes to stringBase64
- encrypting the string (using AES with Key)
- saving the Encrypted string as txt in the System file

  ```
       app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
       {
           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,"Attachments")),
           RequestPath = "/Attachments"
       });
  ```

the above code is how I'm serving the files.
What I want is ?
Is there any way to run any code (code for decrypting the txt file with encrypted string) on the Attachment before serving it to be ready for immediate use.

I'm using netcoreapp3.1

Comment: Is this a single question, or 4 questions? What have you tried for each of these 4 "filters" that you want to run the files through?

Comment: data does not need to be a string to AES be encrypted; AES encrypted data is not a string. If you want to ensure your data is encrypted at rest I would suggest you either understand what you are doing or use a feature build into your hosting platform. Ideally you would do both.

Comment: @Luke it is one question but i wanted to clarify what I'm doing and how my upload endpoint works. Anyway, my question that I have the opposite functionality of the upload endpoint and I want to apply these functionality on the attachment when someone request it.

Comment: @Jodrell yeh I know that but unfortunately, the previous developer did this sequence of actions and then saved the file encrypted string to the database, which now they wanted as I asked (saving the string in the system file). PS I know that this is no where near the best practice but I just want the job done.